# Setter from other class

Tags: c++

I have a class called "StatusInformation", where I want to set the variable _status to true/false, but I am getting only "segmentation fault". I think, that the _status doesn't exist, becouse I call it from the other class. Anybody know how to prevent this error?

StatusInformation.cpp

```
void StatusInformation::SetClientConnectStatus(bool status)
{
    _status = status;
}
```

StatusInformation.h

```
class StatusInformation
{
private:

    bool _status = false;

public:

    void SetClientConnectStatus(bool status);
};
```

CallerClass.cpp

```
_statusInformation = new StatusInformation();

_statusInformation->SetClientConnectStatus(true);
```

CallerClass.h

```
StatusInformation *_statusInformation;
```

Comment: That obviously isn't all of your code, and there isn't enough there to give a sensible answer.

Comment: You're right, this is not all of my code, should I give you 4050 lines of code? This is the important code, and the other code doesn't matter, because it works without this code.

Comment: Why are you putting a pointer declaration in your header?

Comment: @ForJ9 No we don't want 4050 lines, and no, this is not the important code. The code above kind of looks ok. There must be something else that made you think the problem was here?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XWMZD2SD Is this enough? Sorry but the comments are german :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : That link to your code is just giving me code that is missing ArduinoProtocol.

For me, this compiles with 2 warnings about non static data-member initializers, and then runs fine. I really do not believe the segmentation fault can come from this code. The only thing that could cause that would be if

```
_statusInformation = new StatusInformation();
```

Failed and returned 0, making your pointer a NULL pointer. Causing:

```
_statusInformation->SetClientConnectStatus(true);
```

To be equivalent to :

```
NULL->SetClientConnectStatus(true);
```

But that could only happen if you chose to use a no-throw new. Which you much specify. So realistically, the only thing in that code that could make you segmentation fault, cannot happen. Worst case an std::bad_alloc will be thrown.

Comment: I see my mistake, thanks for the hint. I created a new thread in the contructor, and wait for syncronisation. And this gives me a NULL Pointer

Comment: So you actually are getting a NULL pointer? Huh. I also can't compile your full code to run a valgrind on it. (Oh yeah, check into valgrind for all segmentation faults in the future.)

Comment: Will come back to this in the evening. If it's just a segmentation fault, look into valgrind http://valgrind.org/ brilliant whenever you're doing c/c++ and want to look closer into what's happening to the memory.